# GridSearchCV from sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, gridsearchcv

While building a linear regression using the Ridge Regressor from `sklearn` and using `GridSearchCV`, I am getting the below error:

**ValueError**:

```
Invalid parameter 'ridge' for estimator Ridge(). Valid parameters are: ['alpha', 'copy_X', 'fit_intercept', 'max_iter', 'positive', 'random_state', 'solver', 'tol'].
```

My code is as below:

```
X,y = Train_arr.iloc[:,:-1],Train_arr.iloc[:,-1]

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

ridge = Ridge()
param_grid = {'ridge__aplha': np.logspace(-10,10,100)}

ridge_regressor = GridSearchCV(ridge, param_grid,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',cv=5, n_jobs =-1)
ridge_regressor.fit(X,y)
```

Would appreciate if someone can highlight where am I going wrong, which is causing the above value error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the prefix `ridge__`, just use:

```
#        HERE --v
param_grid = {'alpha': np.logspace(-10, 10, 100)}
```

Comment: This will also throw an error as "alpha" is misspelled.

Comment: @lusk. Thanks for pointing this out to me. I corrected the typo.